# Ignoring if statement used for bubble sort

Tags: c++

```
    srand(time(NULL));
    int rand = Randomiser();
    temp = placement[49];
    //Loops variables in array to produce scrolling
    for(i = 0;i<50; i++)
    {
        placement[49-i] = placement[49-(i+1)];
    }
    if(temp==2)
    {
        temp=temp2;
    }
    if(rand>90)
    {
      temp2=temp;
      temp=2;
    }
    placement[0]=temp;
```

So i changed it to something like this and my value is now inserted but the problem is that the value is inserted about 12 times at a time. So 6 placements = 2

Comment: Without seeing the code from the `Randomiser()` function it's hard to determine how the code will execute.

Comment: it's literally just srand(time(NULL);  int random = rand() % 101      return random;

Comment: But im pretty sure its not the randomiser function as i can access the if statement whilst the controlRod variable isnt in the if statement but then i would over input the variable into the array.

Comment: You have a quite complicated way to write 2 to placement[0]. Maybe, you expect is somewhere else? Why don't you do the controlRod part before the loop? Then you would not need controlRod at all.

Comment: @Tobias i've tried placing it everywhere but if its not in the i loop it ignores it. I originally had my if statement in the j loop but then it would never see it for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the following code what you actually want to have?
In this example the i-loop rotates the ring. Note, normally you do not move all the elements but just shift the ring start and address via `(start+i)%size`.

Note, for sorting you have `std::sort` which is much more efficient than bubble sort.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int Randomiser() {
    return rand() % 101;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    std::vector<int> placement(50,0);

    for(int j = 0; j<100; j++)
    {
        int temp, temp2;
        int rand = Randomiser();
        bool controlRod=true;
        if(rand<80)
        {
            temp2 = placement[49];
            placement[49]=2;
        } 
        temp = placement[49];
        for(int i = 0; i<50; i++)
        {
            placement[49-i] = placement[49-(i+1)];
        }
        placement[0] = temp;
    }

    std::cout << "\nThis time in placement[0]: " << placement[0] << "\n";
}
/**
     Local Variables:
     compile-command: "g++ -g test.cc -o test.exe; ./test.exe"
     End:
*/
```

Comment: i've edited my code but the problem is that it is printing 12

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't ignore the `if` statement, it just only evaluates to false after the first iteration of the inner `for` loop. Your code:

```
for( ... )
{
    bool controlRod = true;
    for( ... )
    {
        if( ... && controlRod == true )
        {
               // ...
        }
        // ...
        controlRod = false; // <-- set to false so condition is always false
    }
}
```

If we unroll the inner loop we get something like:

```
for( ... )
{
    bool controlRod = true;

    // iteration 1 ----------------------------------------------------
    if( ... && controlRod == true )
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
    controlRod = false; // <-- set to false so condition is always false

    // iteration 2 ------------------------------------------------------
    if( ... && controlRod == true ) // controlRod was set to false, 
                                    // so this will never be true
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
    controlRod = false; // <-- set to false so condition is always false

    // iteration 3 --------------------------------------------------
    if( ... && controlRod == true ) // controlRod was set to false, 
                                    // so this will never be true
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
    controlRod = false; // <-- set to false so condition is always false

    // more iterations...
}
```

Comment: Yes i see that but when the i loop exits and enters the j loop again then it is once again set to true. Which is what i want. That way there is only a chance to alter the array on the first iteration of i.

Comment: But even if i make the chances of it occurring really high it still never enters the if statement.

Comment: @user3479496 Make the chances 100% by removing the `rand<80` part and look what happens. Maybe, your `Randomiser` is defective?

Comment: @Tobias i have tried this but it still doesnt like it